# Supported OpenGL ES version in WearOS 2

Tags: android, opengl-es, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

What's the currently supported version of OpenGL ES in WearOS 2? Ist OpenGL ES 3.x supported, assuming the hardware can support it? I can't find any documentation for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Play console, Wear OS devices do support GL ES 3.0. Here's a screen grab from the device page for the Huawei Watch 2 on my console:

[image]

Given that Wear OS is Android under the hood, you can usually assume that anything not obvious or documented to be different is the same. So yes, it probably is going to be whatever the hardware supports.